# How do I use Python Django variables in my JS code?

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, html, django

I'm trying to make a vertical side navigation bar populated with categories (dynamic, fetched from django models) where each category has sub-categories (also dynamic and fetched from models). When I refer to classes in my JS code, the code works i.e., upon clicking of a category, the sub-menu consisting of its respective subcategory opens up. But the problem is, when I click on any of the categories, all of them expand to reveal all their sub-categories. I just want one, which is clicked on, to open and stay open.

My HTML:

```
{% block body %}<div class="col-md-12 col-xs-12 body-container leftsidenavigator" style="margin-top:15px;">
    <div class="col-md-12 col-xs-12 leftsidenavigator-inner" style="padding:0px;">
        <h2><center>Categories</center></h2>
            <ul class="catindexlist catlistcat nav-collapse89">
                {% for category in catindexlisted %}
                    <li class="catindexlistitem category-name" style="font-weight:600;padding-right:20px;"><a href="" id="category-name{{category.name}}">{{category.name}}</a></li>
                    <ul style="padding:0px;" class="nav-collapse88">
                        {% for forum in category|forumindexlistbycat %}
                            <li class="catlistforum forum-name" id="{{category.name}}{{forum.name}}" style="padding-right:10px;"><a href="{{ forum.get_absolute_url }}">{{forum.name}}</a></li>
                        {% endfor %}</ul>
                {% endfor %}
            </ul></div></div>{% endblock %}
```

My non-ideal but working Javascript:

```
$(function() {
   $(".catlistforum").hide();
   $(".category-name a").click(function(e) {
     e.preventDefault();
     $(".catlistforum").slideToggle();
     if(!($(this).parent('li').parent('div').siblings('div').children('ul').children('div').is(":visible"))){
            $(this).parent('li').parent('div').siblings('div').children('ul').children('div').is(":visible").slideToggle();
     }});
 })
```

This is what appears in the console of chrome dev tools:
[image]

I need something like this to work:

```
$(function() {
   $(".catlistforum").hide();
   $(".category-name a").click(function(e) {
     e.preventDefault();
     $(".catlistforum").slideToggle();
     if(!($(this).parent('li').siblings('div').children('ul').children('div').is(":visible"))){
            $(this).parent('li').siblings('div').children('ul').children('div').is(":visible").slideToggle();
     }});
 })
```

This code, when I click on any category, reloads the page and no sub-menu is shown. Please keep in mind that I've used for loops, so the final HTML will have several categories with each having several sub-categories.

How can I refer to IDs dynamically generated by Django? Is this a placement issue of where I place my script in the page-because, through the chain of `% extends %` and `% includes %`, this script comes with other scripts at the bottom of the page, after my footer is rendered. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure to have understood perfectly as 3 things bother me in your code :

1. In both your lists, you use a 'div' between a 'ul' and a 'li'. I'm not sure if it is correct / can cause issues. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/ul
2. In your first Jquery code, you use the function child(), did you mean children() ?
3. In your first Jquery code, I don't understand the 'if' statement. I may have read it too quickly but it seems to me that it says : "If no unrelated sub-menu is visible, then slideToggle all unrelated and visible sub-menus". Not sure if it's my mistake or not.

But if I understand what you want to do (display the sub-menu of the clicked category, and hide all others), based on your html structure (regardless of my issue nº1, then) I think this would work (once again : based on your html structure) :

```
    $(function() {
      $(".catlistforum").hide();
        $(".category-name a").click(function(e) {
          e.preventDefault();
          $(".nav-collapse88").hide();
          $(this).parent('li').parent('div').next('.nav-collapse88').show();
        });
     })
```

Personnally I would change the Html structure to quit the 'divs' mentionned above. You could maybe use a 'li' for each category, containing two 'divs' : one with class 'catindexlistitem' for the displayed item, and one - hidden with class 'nav-collapse88' - for the submenu. Here again in Javascript you could use the same steps as above : hide all '.nav-collapse' and show only the one next to the clicked item.

Hope it helps, good luck

Comment: Hi, I've taken your advice and simplified my HTML structure. However, the problem remains- whether I use your JS or mine. In fact, your JS reloads the page and it returns to an all collapsed state. I tried adding `e.preventDefault();` to your code, which turned the links into bricks-nothing happens when I click the links. Can you take a look at the new HTML structure please? Thanks,

Comment: You're right `e.preventDefault()` was needed! From the JS code I posted, did you quit the `.parent('div')` part ? It would no longer be needed. If it still doesn't work, could you post what tells the browser Inspector (what appears in the Console section) when you click on any item ?

Comment: Yes, I quit the .parent('div') part (updated the code in the question). Still the issue remains that when I click on a category, all of the categories expand rather than only the respective one expanding. I've also just updated a screen shot of what appears in the browser inspector in the question.